# Decorate consumer and resolve services in the consumer (IServiceProvider) (masstransit)

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to use MassTransit to implement mediator pattern for the Commands and Handlers (CQRS). That works - when a command is dispatched, the correct handler is invoked.

Now, I'd like to decorate these handlers (**not** for cross-cutting concerns, such as logging) but I'd like to add decorators to specific handlers (so I can apply some permissions or authorization rules without adding code to the handler itself). This means that I want to decorate the handler for Command A with a certain function, but not the handler for Command B.

So, I figured I should use filters for this. And I managed to do it by using [definitions](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/definitions.html) - so now when a specific consumer with specific message type is invoked by the mediator, first all the filters defined for it are invoked. And that works fine.

And now we get to the issue: I want to inject/resolve some services in the filters, as they would need to access the database or do some other validations in order to be meaningful. And this is where I'm stuck.
Here is a draft pull request of the above scenario: adding filter per consumer, and the problem is in this file: https://github.com/bdn-mca/ModularMonolith.Poc/pull/2/files#diff-980261987a7df5d217950a20fccccf88c775bf6c72bf3d536e44d9768b86c51d

I know MassTransit has many many functionalities, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scoped filters to resolve filter instances at runtime from the container.

In your consumer definition, just add to the receive endpoint configurator:

```cs
var csp = _provider.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationServiceProvider>();
cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(DemoValidator<>), csp);
```

You'd need to add `IServiceProvider` to your constructor definition, and store it in a member variable to use when `Configure` is called.

[Documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html)
[Sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters)

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. I'm a bit confused here:
Should I add `cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(DemoValidator<>), _provider);` to the [ConsumerDefinition here](https://github.com/bdn-mca/ModularMonolith.Poc/blob/268bc47aec70347632621e215306e858524e4503/src/Module1/Module1.Application/Commands/Demo.cs#L46) (because there is no such method)
- Or in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Updated answer, and yes you can put it in the consumer definition.

Comment: Thanks. Using your suggestion now made the application execute **all** filters for **all** consumers, while I'd like consumer for command A to have certain filters, and consumer for command B to have different filters (depending on what is specified in the consumer definition).

Comment: But you nudged me in the right direction so now I solved my problem. Here is the [pull request](https://github.com/bdn-mca/ModularMonolith.Poc/pull/2/files), and the 2 places of interest: [ConsumerDefinition](https://github.com/bdn-mca/ModularMonolith.Poc/blob/8b1a573ef9ae6551a046457fcc15567bed25900d/src/Module1/Module1.Application/Commands/Demo.cs#L56-L62) and [Filter](https://github.com/bdn-mca/ModularMonolith.Poc/blob/8b1a573ef9ae6551a046457fcc15567bed25900d/src/Module1/Module1.Application/Validators/DemoValidator.cs#L26-L38).